# libeigen-cdd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ECLIPSE C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, dynamic, shared

Yet another shared library question.

I am trying to run a code that depends on a package which resides in a separate workspace, /home/foo/opt/bar-workspace. 
I can build the package inside this bar-workspace with `make build` and run the executable, but I want to use the package in my ECLIPSE workspace, /home/foo/workspace.

I am using Release configuration. The code compiles, but when I run it in ECLIPSE, I get the error

```
    libeigen-cdd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In ECLIPSE IDE, libeigen-cdd.so path is added to Library Search Path(-L) and eigen-cdd is added to Libraries(-l). I also tried adding the path of libeigen-cdd.so as an environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH, which resides in /build/release/src of the package, but it did not help.Plus, even if I succeed in this, there are other .so libraries the code depends, so I wonder after I succeed in this, how can I add all those .so as environment variables, as they all reside in seperate locations.

Thanks.

Comment: You could, maybe, use a dependency manager like conan [http://conan.io] coupled with cmake and it will much easier to manage your dependencies and you will be able to generate an eclipse project with cmake. It takes a little longer to learn at the beginning but you'll gain on the long-term.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I would eventually have to learn those. I will give it a shot.